# request for member view in something not a structure or union

Tags: iphone

I have this error when i build my application iphone:
request for member view in something not a structure or union on [CommuneSlider.view removeFromSuperview];

the code:
- (void) CommuneSelected {

```
CommuneDetailsViewController *com = [[CommuneDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommuneDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navig = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                               initWithRootViewController:com];
[self setCommuneDetails:(CommuneDetailsViewController *) navig];
[navig setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[com release];
[navig release];


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.8];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:window cache:YES];

[CommuneSlider.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:[CommuneDetails view]];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

need HELP

Answer (score 1):

ok this is AzurGuideAppDelegate.h:

```
@class CommuneSliderController, AccueilViewController,CommuneDetailsViewController;

@interface AzurGuideAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    AccueilViewController *AccueilController;
    CommuneSliderController *CommuneSlider;
    CommuneDetailsViewController *CommuneDetails;
    UINavigationController *navigationControl;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AccueilViewController *AccueilController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CommuneSliderController *CommuneSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CommuneDetailsViewController *CommuneDetails;


- (void) goBack;
- (void) goFront;
- (void) CommuneSelected;

@end
```

and here the AzurGuideAppDelegate.m where i defined my method:

```
#import "AzurGuideAppDelegate.h"
#import "AccueilViewController.h"


@implementation AzurGuideAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize AccueilController;
@synthesize CommuneSlider;
@synthesize CommuneDetails;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch

    [window addSubview:AccueilController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void) CommuneSelected {

    CommuneDetailsViewController *com = [[CommuneDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CommuneDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navig = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                                   initWithRootViewController:com];
    [self setCommuneDetails:(CommuneDetailsViewController *) navig];
    [navig setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [com release];
    [navig release];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.8];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:window cache:YES];
    [CommuneSlider.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[CommuneDetails view]];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

and my CommuneSliderController class:

```
#import "AzurGuideAppDelegate.h"
#import "CommuneSliderController.h"
#import "CoverFlowView.h"
#import "CoverViewController.h"

#define CVC_VIEW_TAG        999

@implementation CommuneSliderController


- (IBAction) goFront:(id) sender {
    AzurGuideAppDelegate *main = (AzurGuideAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [main goFront]; 
}

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view = contentView;
    [contentView release];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    CoverViewController *cvc = [[CoverViewController alloc] init];
    cvc.view.tag = CVC_VIEW_TAG;
    [self.view addSubview:cvc.view];    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the error line:

request for member view in something not a structure or union on [CommuneSlider.view removeFromSuperview];

It seems to indicate that CommuneSlider does not have a "view" member.  The name of the variable makes me think it is a UIControl, not a sub-class of UIViewController (which would have a view property).

Are you sure you don't want something like:

```
[CommuneSliderController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

If this were C++, I'd say "there's a pointer to a class, and you try to say `pClass.foo` instead of `pClass->foo`", or the type whose "`view`" variable you try to access is unknown due to some reason. Maybe this could help with Objective-C as well.

Comment: In fact it is in objective C and communeSlider  is a property that I defined it in myAppDelegate

@synthesize CommuneSlider;
@synthesize CommuneDetails;

Comment: Well, is it a pointer or a struct/class? You see, I've seen these errors only in C++ context, and have little to no experience with Objective-C